# Simulation of common gestures in amazon device farm

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, testing

I am performing testing of my application in Amazon Device Farm. I am accessing Samsung Galaxy S3, Apple iPhone 5C and Samsung galaxy Tablet devices through Remote Access in Amazon Device Farm.

I have to perform simulation of common gestures like Zoom In, Zoom Out, shake, glimp etc in ADF. I am not able to perform these actions. Also I haven’t found anything regarding the same .

If anyone has verified common gestures in Amazon Device Farm then please provide me the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

Currently there is no way to input all the gestures you mentioned. 
One way to try subset of the gestures on iOS device in remote access session would be to enable Assistive Touch under Accessibility menu in general settings.

For Android though there is no out of the box Assistive touch support provided by the OS. 
Although there are no immediate plans to add support for these, I have noted down your request for this feature.

Hope this answers your question.